# How to seal an interior house door without taking it down?

Tags: sound-proofing, wind

My bedroom has 2 entry way: one single door towards a hallway and a double doors into the living room. I would like to seal off the double door and only use the single door, any suggestions on how to dampen the sound and windproof a double door? Thank you.

Comment: permanently seal/close

Comment: More information please. Images, door construction and materials

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does the bedroom have another escape path(windows)?  If not, sealing the second door might not be allowed under building/fire codes.  Adding weather stripping to the double doors should be enough for your wants.  Adding a lock you can open from the bedroom will keep it closed.

Comment: Is there a lock?